# ENTRYPOINT and CMD with build arguments

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This doesn't work:

```
FROM alpine:3.7

# build argument with default value
ARG PING_HOST=localhost

# environment variable with same value
ENV PING_HOST=${PING_HOST}

# act as executable
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/ping"]

# default command
CMD ["${PING_HOST}"]
```

It should be possible to build an image with build-arg and to start a container with an environment variable to override cmd as well.

```
docker build -t ping-image .
docker run -it --rm ping-image
```

Error: ping: bad address '${PING_HOST}'

UPDATE:

```
FROM alpine:3.7

# build argument with default value
ARG PING_HOST=localhost

# environment variable with same value
ENV PING_HOST ${PING_HOST}

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

# act as executable
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]

# default command
CMD $PING_HOST
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

/bin/ping $PING_HOST
```

This works because the entrypoint.sh enables variable substitution as expected.

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: It's true that `CMD` executes the given command literally (no variable or other shell metacharacter expansion).  This is true regardless of wheter or not you are using build arguments. What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

For CMD to expand variables, you need to arrange for a shell because shell is responsible for expanding environment variables, not Docker. You can do that like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"]
CMD ["-c" , "ping ${PING_HOST}"]
```

OR

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "ping ${PING_HOST}"]
```